# jQuery & Vendor Conflicts - Convert to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have build a 'wizard' of sorts and used JQuery. Everything works great until I put it on the Vendor page - none of the actions function. I have edited the scripting to be more unique - to avoid conflicting class/ids.

Ultimately, I am now trying alter my JQuery into JavaScript. I am not familiar enough with JQuery to know what I am doing.

Hoping someone is willing to assist me, TIA.

```js
var base = {
    productFilterSetup: function () {
        $('.productFilter').each(
            function () {
                var tmp = new base.filterGroup_uni(this);
                tmp.setup();
            });
    },
    filterGroup_uni: function (filter_group_uni) {
        var me = this;
        me.target_element = filter_group_uni;
        me.active_element_index = 0;
        me.setup = function () {
            $(filter_group_uni).find('input[class=option],input[class=sub-option]').bind('click', function () {
                me.update(this);
            });
        };
        me.update = function (target_radio_uni) {
            var fieldsets = $(me.target_element).find('.fieldset'),
                len = fieldsets.length,
                i = 0,
                j = 0,
                radios_uni,
                radios_uni_len,
                options = [],
                options_buffer = '',
                num_of_steps = 0;

            for (i = 1; i <= num_of_steps + 1; i += 1) {
                if ($('.fieldset.step' + i).length > 0) {
                    num_of_steps += 1;
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < num_of_steps; i += 1) {
                if ($(target_radio_uni).parents('.fieldset.step' + (i + 1)).length > 0) {
                    for (j = i; j < num_of_steps; j += 1) {
                        $('.fieldset.step' + (j + 2) + ' input[class=option],input[class=sub-option]').attr('checked', false);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
                radios_uni = $(fieldsets[i]).find('input[class=option],input[class=sub-option]');
                radios_uni_len = radios_uni.length;
                for (j = 0; j < radios_uni_len; j += 1) {
                    if ($(radios_uni[j]).is(':checked')) {
                        options.push(j + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            fieldsets.addClass('hide-uni');
            $('.fieldset.option0').removeClass('hide-uni');
            for (i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
                options_buffer += options[i];
                $('.fieldset.option' + options_buffer).removeClass('hide-uni');
            }
        };
    }
};

$(
    function () {
        base.productFilterSetup();
    });
```

```css
.option-style {
  margin:10px 0;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  border: 2px solid #ED780F !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #0F3D70;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.option-style2 {
  margin:10px 0;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  border: 2px solid #ED780F !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #0F3D70;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.modal-link {
  color: #ED780F;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.modal-link:hover {
  color: #71B9F8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.option-result-title {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #0F3D70;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 0 10px 5px;
  border-bottom:2px solid #ED780F !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.option-result {
  margin:auto;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  width: 70%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.option-result:hover {
    color: #ED780F;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.option-result2 {
  margin:auto;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.other-result {
  padding: 25px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 18px !important;
}
.modal-link2{
    font-size: 18px !important;
    color: #0F3D70 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.modal-link2:hover{
    color: #ED780F !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hide-uni {
  display:none;
}

.option-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #0F3D70;
}

.option-subtitle{
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #0F3D70;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.row-style {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
}

.option-subtitle:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ED780F;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

fieldset.step1.option0 {
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

/* Hide Radio button */

input[class=option],input[class=sub-option] {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>



            <form action="" id="unique_id" class="productFilter">
                <fieldset class="fieldset step1 option0">
                    <legend class="option-title"> title</legend>
                    <p class="option-subtitle">
                        <input class="option" id="question_1" name="group_1" type="radio" />
                        <label for="question_1">1</label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="option-subtitle">
                        <input class="option" id="question_2" name="group_1" type="radio" />
                        <label for="question_2">2</label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="option-subtitle">
                        <input class="option" id="question_3" name="group_1" type="radio" />
                        <label for="question_3">3</label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="option-subtitle">
                        <input class="option" id="question_4" name="group_1" type="radio" />
                        <label for="question_4">4</label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="option-subtitle">
                        <input class="option" id="question_5" name="group_1" type="radio" />
                        <label for="question_5">5</label>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="fieldset hide-uni step2 option1 option-style">
                    <legend class="option-result-title">1</legend>
                    <p class="option-result">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium quia repudiandae quo earum reprehenderit, fugiat consectetur eum! Maiores consectetur veniam officia, fugit molestias deleniti cumque assumenda voluptatem velit reiciendis saepe.
                    </p>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="fieldset hide-uni step3 option2 option-style">
                    <legend class="option-result-title">2</legend>
                    <div class="row-style">
                    <p class="option-result">
                        <input class="sub-option" id="question_2_1" name="group_3" type="radio" />
                        <label for="question_2_1">2a</label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="option-result">
                        <input class="sub-option" id="question_2_2" name="group_3" type="radio" />
                        <label for="question_2_2">2b</label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="option-result">
                        <input class="sub-option" id="question_2_3" name="group_3" type="radio" />
                        <label for="question_2_3">2c</label>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="fieldset hide-uni step3 option21 option-style2">
                    <legend class="option-result-title">2aa</legend>
                    <p class="option-result2">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium quia repudiandae quo earum reprehenderit, fugiat consectetur eum! Maiores consectetur veniam officia, fugit molestias deleniti cumque assumenda voluptatem velit reiciendis saepe.
                    </p>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="fieldset hide-uni step3 option22 option-style2">
                    <legend class="option-result-title">2bb</legend>
                    <p class="option-result2">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium quia repudiandae quo earum reprehenderit, fugiat consectetur eum! Maiores consectetur veniam officia, fugit molestias deleniti cumque assumenda voluptatem velit reiciendis saepe.
                    </p>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="fieldset hide-uni step3 option23 option-style2">
                    <legend class="option-result-title">2cc</legend>
                    <p class="option-result2">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium quia repudiandae quo earum reprehenderit, fugiat consectetur eum! Maiores consectetur veniam officia, fugit molestias deleniti cumque assumenda voluptatem velit reiciendis saepe.
                    </p>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="fieldset hide-uni step4 option3 option-style">
                    <legend class="option-result-title">3</legend>
                    <p class="option-result">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium quia repudiandae quo earum reprehenderit, fugiat consectetur eum! Maiores consectetur veniam officia, fugit molestias deleniti cumque assumenda voluptatem velit reiciendis saepe.
                    </p>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="fieldset hide-uni step4 option4 option-style">
                    <legend class="option-result-title">4</legend>
                    <p class="option-result">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium quia repudiandae quo earum reprehenderit, fugiat consectetur eum! Maiores consectetur veniam officia, fugit molestias deleniti cumque assumenda voluptatem velit reiciendis saepe.
                    </p>

                </fieldset>


                <fieldset class="fieldset hide-uni step5 option5 option-style">
                    <legend class="option-result-title">5</legend>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium quia repudiandae quo earum reprehenderit, fugiat consectetur eum! Maiores consectetur veniam officia, fugit molestias deleniti cumque assumenda voluptatem velit reiciendis saepe.
                    </p>

                </fieldset>

            </form>

    



   
        

</body>
```

Comment: _Everything works great until I put it on the Vendor page_ This really doesn't mean anything to us. Switching to Vanilla JS without knowing what is going wrong with your jQuery would be very difficult.

Comment: Nothing functions. Clicking the 'buttons' results in nothing happening.

Comment: Your example works, so without us know what the actual conflicts are, it will be very hard to help. When you use this on your "vendors" page, are there any errors in your dev console? Also, we don't know what your "vendors" page is.